# Usage of std::destroy_at() in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have simple code snippet which is trying to free the memory using `std::destroy_at()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
  ~base()
  {
    cout << "des" << endl;
  }
};
int main()
{
  {
    base* b1 = new base();
    std::destroy_at(b1); // destructor is executed for b1 object (but memory is not freed for b1)
  }
return 0;
}
```

Can someone guide me how to use `destroy_at()` for freeing the memory? Same behavior observed for primitive data types also. 
Using VS2017 compiler latest.

Comment: `std::destroy_at` doesn't free memory.

Answer (score 12):

`std::destroy_at()` is not meant to deallocate memory according to [[specialized.destroy]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/memory#specialized.destroy-1) it is meant to call the destructor of the object:

> template<class T>
>      void destroy_at(T* location);
>   1.    Effects: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> location->~T();
> ```

The [cppreference entry](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) gives an example of why this might be needed. In this case we have used placement new into a buffer and there is no need to free the memory:

```
struct Tracer {
    int value;
    ~Tracer() { std::cout << value << " destructed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    alignas(Tracer) unsigned char buffer[sizeof(Tracer) * 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        new(buffer + sizeof(Tracer) * i) Tracer{i}; //manually construct objects

    auto ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Tracer*>(buffer));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        std::destroy_at(ptr + i);
}
```

The proposal that brought this in [Extending memory management tools](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r2.html) says:

> It is common for both the standard library and user libraries **to manage memory without the use of standard-compliant allocators**. They **may use internal buffers (like optional)** or use an allocator model that does not manage object lifetime [bde] [sgi] [eastl] [bitsquid]. Such alternative allocator models are common in efficiency-critical applications.
>   ....

Comment: Considering how hard it is to get the pseudo-destructor name right for some types (especially if they are aliased), this is sorely needed.

Comment: You might also point out that `delete b1` is the proper way to both destroy the pointee and free the storage the pointer denotes. "You can't use X to do Y" is great, but would be improved by adding "use Z instead."